# Can I create a table definition from an existing sql table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way for me to automatically create a table definition from a previously created table in mysql?

I use MAMP to write and test websites, and use localhost to play with, error correct and generally tweak databases before I create the database through my actual host. While the task is not arduous, I end up spending a lot of time recreating table definitions.

Apologies if I have used bad keywords for my searches, but every time I look for an answer I get sent through to paid products when I'd much rather muck in and do some code.

Working primarily through php and mysql admin

Comment: It's quite simple using phpMyAdmin. You simple export the table and select the option to export the structure. I'm fairly sure you should be able to do the same when you export using mysql admin

Comment: The `sql-server` tag is about sql-server, which is not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that regarding the field definition using a CTAS (Create Table As Select) statement, but it won't duplicate keys, indexes and such.

```
create table YourNewTable as
select * from YourExistingTable
```

Or, if you want only the structure and not the data:

```
create table YourNewTable as
select * from YourExistingTable where false
```

-edit-

On second thought, reading your question again, you may be looking for the SHOW CREATE statement:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE YourExistingTable
```

This will output the statement needed to create your table, so you can easily execute that statement on the host. This way, you can fairly easily copy the table structure from your local environment to your host.

See [SHOW CREATE TABLE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html).

It may be worth it to install a tool like PHPMyAdmin. It will be a great help in executing queries and perform all kinds of management tasks. You can even export your entire database structure, and if you like the data as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for this:

> MySQL provides two ways to create a table based on another table:
>
> - CREATE TABLE ... SELECT creates a table and populates it from the result set returned by an arbitrary SELECT statement. In this case,
>     the “other table” is the set of rows and columns retrieved by the
>     SELECT.
> - CREATE TABLE ... LIKE creates an empty table using the definition of another existing table.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t
-> (i INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> PRIMARY KEY (i))
-> ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The result of CREATE TABLE ... LIKE differs from the result of using CREATE TABLE ...
to create an empty table. Either of the following statements will create an empty
copy of the table t:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE copy1 SELECT * FROM t WHERE 0;
mysql> CREATE TABLE copy2 LIKE t;
```

However, the resulting copies differ in the amount of information retained from the original
table structure:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE copy1\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Table: copy1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `copy1` (
`i` int(11) NOT NULL default ‘0’
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE copy2\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Table: copy2
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `copy2` (
`i` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
PRIMARY KEY (`i`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> The CREATE TABLE ... SELECT statement copies the column name and data
>   type from the original table, but does not retain the PRIMARY KEY
>   index information or the AUTO_INCREMENT column attribute information.
>   The new table also uses the default storage engine, rather than the
>   storage engine utilized by table t. The copy created with CREATE TABLE
>   ... LIKE has none of these problems.

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Answer (score -1):

For creating a table without Create Table statement in Sql server:

```
Select * into NewTable from oldTable where 1=0
```

--where 1=0 would not copy the data

Comment: Will that work? Doc says: [MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL extension.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Comment: @GolezTrol I have answered for the sql server tag.